# Trying to output contents of array

Tags: templating, craft3

I'm trying to find a way of using php's print_r to output the entries that were pulled from the entries in the database. I'm pretty much brand new to Craft cms coming from Laravel, so a common thing I've done in the past with querying the database is seeing what I got back by outputting my array using either print_r or laravel's dd($array) during testing for a sanity check. I can't seem to find an easy way of doing this in Craft. This is what I've tried so far:

```
{% set listItems = craft.entries().section('todoList').all() %}

{{ listItems }}
```

The {{ listItems }} of course gives the array to string conversion error when rendering the page, so I tried doing:

```
{{ listItems | join }}
```

but that only outputs the title of the entry. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like using `{{ dump(listItems) }}` gave me enough to work with. I forgot to mention I had tried this before. It didn't work the last time, but I suspect I gave it an incompatible data type.